# Get result from documentdb stored procedure c#

Tags: c#, json, azure-cosmosdb

How can I get result data from documetdb stored procedure? Please see below code

```
public static object GetDocument(string CollectionName, string StoredProcedureName, List<object> ProcedureParams)
{
        Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoredProcedure sproc = GetDocumentStoredProcedure(CollectionName, StoredProcedureName).Result;

        dynamic result = client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>(sproc.SelfLink, ProcedureParams);
        if (result != null)
        {
            var ssd = result.Response;
        }            
        return result;            
}

public static async Task<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoredProcedure> GetDocumentStoredProcedure(string CollectionName, string StoredProcedureName)
{
        Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentCollection collection = GetDocumentCollection(CollectionName).Result; //Getting collection details from function

        if (client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collection.SelfLink).Where(coll => coll.Id == StoredProcedureName).ToArray().Any())
        {
            return client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collection.SelfLink).Where(coll => coll.Id == StoredProcedureName).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return await client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(collection.SelfLink, new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoredProcedure
        {
            Id = StoredProcedureName
        });
}
```

Error :

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not contain a definition for 'Response'

The stored procedure expected result if json data. Please help

Comment: In which line you get the exception?

Comment: Am not getting result on if (result != null)
        {
            var ssd = result.Response;
        } Do u have any code to get data from documentdb stored procedure, so that i can refer it. Exception is on  code - var ssd = result.Response;. I think this is not the right way to get data

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `await` to your line 5 like this:

```
dynamic result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>(sproc.SelfLink, ProcedureParams);
```